# Getting provider name of layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, data-source

In QGIS 3.16.5-Hannover, with PyQGIS I want to get the provider name of a selected layer. I need to know if it's an `ESRI Shapefile` layer or a `PostGIS` layer for example.

[image: Information]

I don't see how to get this value in [`QgsProviderRegistry`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsProviderRegistry.html), or in [`QgsVectorDataProvider`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Vector/QgsVectorDataProvider.html).

I try this:

```py
# Get the name of a selected layer from a combo box
selectedLayerName = self.mMapLayerComboBox.currentText()
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(selectedLayerName)[0]

# Could it be something like this ?
layerProvider = layer.getProvider()
```

Is there a way with PyQGIS to know the provider of a selected vector layer? (like metadata information)

Comment: For a QgsVectorLayer, that is indeed the way to get the provider. You add features to the provider to put them in the layer.

Comment: And how to get the source type of a vector layer with `PyQGIS` ? (`ESRI Shapefile`, `PostGIS`...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the information (storage) which you have highlighted in your screenshot you could use:

```py
selectedLayerName = self.mMapLayerComboBox.currentText()
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(selectedLayerName)[0]
layerProvider = layer.dataProvider()
layerStorage = layerProvider.storageType()
print(layerStorage)
```

The `storageType()` method, according to the [docs](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html#a4820a4cd54ded3f613e08bf4bc59a737):

> Returns the permanent storage type for this layer as a friendly name.

So you will get values like:

"GPKG"

"ESRI Shapefile"

"MapInfo File"

Comment: storageType(), cool! Should have a deeper look in the docs next time :-)

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I expected.

Answer (score 7):

For the selected Layer in the Layer tree:

```py
my_lyr = iface.activeLayer()
```

For your combo-Box:

```py
my_lyr = mMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()
```

Get the data provider:

```py
dp = my_lyr.dataProvider()
```

Get the provider name:

```py
name = dp.name()
```

Will return something like `ogr`, `wms`, `postgres`, ...

For deeper insights I recommend the data source specification:

```py
uri = dp.uri()
```

Will give you e.g.

> <QgsDataSourceUri:
> crs='EPSG:3857&format&type=xyz&url=http://tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0'>
> (wms)

or

> <QgsDataSourceUri:
> /home/jxxxxx/Dokumente/QGIS/.../.../my_document.ods|layername='my
> layer'> (ogr)

Comment: That's it. In my example I get `ogr` for ESRI Shapefiles or `postgres` values for `PostgreSQL/PostGIS` database layers.

Comment: @Ben W's answer solves your issue better than mine

Answer (score 4):

From the `layer` instance, you can [get the provider type](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#a21d77a908e4bdebeae25e8599812997f) with:

```py
layer.providerType()
```